# How to use Outer for loop value in inner for loop in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm doing Django Project. Here I am trying to use Outer for loop data in inner for loop in Django Template. Help me in that i did mistake in inner for loop i don't know how to solve this.

views.py

```
def test_view(request):
    if 'username' in request.session:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            offers_objs = Offers.objects.all().values()
            data = Signup.objects.all().values()
            return render(request, 'index.html',{'offers_objs':offers_objs, 'data': data})
```

index.html

```
{% for i in offers_objs %}
    <div class="divi" style="height: 410px">
        <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="Images" width="300px" height="auto"/>
             <p>Offer Des: {{ i.description }}</p>
             <p>Address: {{ i.address }}</p>
             <p>Offer id: {{ i.offer_id }}</p>
    </div>
        {% for {{ i.username }} in data %}
            <p>{{ name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique= True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique= True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique= True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models. CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Offers(models.Model):
    offer_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: This is unclear. What is `comm.username`? Why are you using variable lookup within a tag?

Comment: sorry by mistake i updated my question.

Comment: username is a Offers table column i want to access Name from Data table using username.

Comment: Well you wouldn't do it like this. Please show your Signup and offers models; how are they related?

Comment: So is Offers.username supposed to link to Signup.username?

Comment: I have updated my question. In offers username column it stores data using sessions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, using Offers username I want to access Signup row data.

Comment: Now I'm more confused. What does "In offers username column it stores data using sessions" mean"? What exactly is in that column?

Comment: once user login, i created a session through out the project. In `request.session` i'm passing logedin user username from Signup table. If i post some offers(i did'n mentiond in question) i'm storing session data to Offers username column(`username = request.session['username']`). Now i'm getting Offers Table username, using  this offers username data i want to access Signup Table row.

Comment: Look, you shouldn't be doing any of this. It is hugely horribly dangerous to write your own login system, and there is no need to do this. Remove your Signup model and use Django's built-in authentication framework. Then, give Offers a ForeignKey to Django's User model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Removing the `{{ }}` in `{% for {{ i.username }} in data %}` should fix it.

```html
{% for i in offers_objs %}
    <div class="divi" style="height: 410px">
        <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="Images" width="300px" height="auto"/>
             <p>Offer Des: {{ i.description }}</p>
             <p>Address: {{ i.address }}</p>
             <p>Offer id: {{ i.offer_id }}</p>
    </div>
        {% for i.username in data %}
            <p>{{ name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```